# Подскажите по вёрстке

Tags: css, bootstrap

В чём может быть проблема в вёрстке, при уменьшении экрана после 990px контент фиксируется на 990px и появляться прокрутка. Это правильно, но меню всё равно продолжает уменьшаться, в чём может быть проблема?
На скриншоте пример вывода
Файлы вёрстки можно посмотреть тут: https://yadi.sk/d/eW--fg1UftBKG

Помогите решить проблему кто знает, уже голову сломал с этим

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Comment: У Вас меню имеет классы col-md-* ? Скорее всего у Вас там col-sm-* или col-xs-*

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно указать минимальную ширину для `body`:

```
body{
    min-width: 990px;
}
```

Comment: Ок спс, так работает. 
Я ещё ставил min-width: 990px; у .container, теперь понял, что надо только у body поставить и всё нормально выводится